# I can't turn on/off my bluetooth on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

Why i can't turn on/off my bluetooth? It has worked very well before since i formated the windows.I'm missing any driver or what?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Under _Other devices_ you have _Unknown device_ what means that there is no driver installed for this device. Install the missing driver and see if the issue remains.

Answer (score 0):

According to your screenshots, You can't switch on bluetooth because Windows cannot sense an existing bluetooth device. This has happened because :

1. **The bluetooth device hasn't been inserted properly.** This is unlikely since it was working fine on your old OS but give it a try if your bluetooth device is a pci-e card or a usb dongle.
2. **The drivers for you your device haven't been installed.** This is more likely. You can find the drivers on the manufacturer's website. Even if you can't find drivers for your exact model, drivers from the same manufacturer usually work. From your screenshot, the device manager lists an `Unknown Device` which is probably your device without the needed drivers.